# Java Driver for MongoDB: Can't resolve function toJson()

Tags: java, mongodb

I wrote the following code based on the link
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/getting-started/quick-start/ (See title "Find All Documents in a Collection"):

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        MongoCollection collection = database.getCollection("test");
        MongoCursor cursor = collection.find().iterator();
        try {
           while(cursor.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
           }
        } finally {
           cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get an error that function toJson() can't be resolved. Do you have any idea how I can make this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the missing type. The cursor next method returns the type of the collection.Below example uses bson's Document type.

```
import org.bson.Document;

MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    try {
       while(cursor.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
       }
    } finally {
       cursor.close();
    }
```

Comment: thanks. But why the '<Document'> was missing in the documentation? Is it a mistake?

Comment: I just looked at the link you provided. Seems like the title you refer has a Document type too.